# How to tackle time limit exceeded error in leetcode

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I've wrote my code for Longest Common Prefix in LeetCode, but it was returned "Time Limit Exceeded".

There is no specific error message, so I have no idea how to fix my code to pass test cases.

```py
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:

        #find the number of shortest characters
        shortest_num = 0
        nums = [0] * len(strs)
        for i in range(len(strs)):
            nums[i] = len(strs[i])
            shortest_num = min(nums)

        l1 = strs[0]
        l2 = strs[1]
        l3 = strs[2]


        for j in range(shortest_num):
            tmp = ""
            while l1[j] == l2[j] and l2[j] == l3[j]:
                tmp += l1[j]
            candidate.append(tmp)

        print(max(candidate))
```

Error Message

```
Time Limit Exceeded
```

Comment: Time Limit Exceeded means they ran your code on a bigger input, and the code is slow. You need to optimize your code to reduce runtime complexity.

Comment: Note that without knowing what your task actually is, it is very difficult to help you optimize your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is faster to always use list comprehensions.
For example to get the list of string lengths use the following

```
lens = [len(x) for x in strs]
min_len = min(lens)
```

Comment: it would be better to do `lens = (len(x) for x in strs)` as generators are mostly faster then lists

Answer (score 9):

This error comes when you don't have written code in Good Time complexity.
When the Leetcode system ran your code with bigger input your code did not run in optimal time.
There may be some known Algorithm to solve your problem statement. Search the question statement on internet you will find some Algorithm to solve this problem.